# Magento 2 - How to show text box field on selecting "Other" option in customer attribute dropdown

Tags: magento2, magento2.3, magento2.2, magento2.4

I have created customer attribute from admin, It is a drop-down. In the drop-down, i have one value as "other", once user select "other" I need to show text box and save that value.

How can i achieve this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

To create dependent customer attributes follow the below steps:

1.Create customer attribute for dropdown on path
**app/code/Vendor/Extension/Setup/Patch/Data/AddDropdownAttribute.php**

```
<?php

namespace Vendor\Extension\Setup\Patch\Data;

use Vendor\Extension\Model\Options;
use Magento\Catalog\Ui\DataProvider\Product\ProductCollectionFactory;
use Magento\Customer\Model\Customer;
use Magento\Customer\Model\ResourceModel\Attribute;
use Magento\Eav\Model\Config;
use Magento\Eav\Setup\EavSetupFactory;
use Magento\Framework\Exception\AlreadyExistsException;
use Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleDataSetupInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\Patch\DataPatchInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\Patch\PatchRevertableInterface;
use Psr\Log\LoggerInterface;

/**
 * Create Customer Attribute
 */
class AddDropdownAttribute implements DataPatchInterface, PatchRevertableInterface
{
    /**
     * @var ModuleDataSetupInterface
     */
    private ModuleDataSetupInterface $moduleDataSetup;

    /**
     * @var EavSetupFactory
     */
    private EavSetupFactory $eavSetupFactory;

    /**
     * @var LoggerInterface
     */
    private $logger;

    /**
     * @var Config
     */
    private Config $eavConfig;

    /**
     * @var Attribute
     */
    private Attribute $attributeResource;

    /**
     * CustomerAttribute Constructor
     * @param EavSetupFactory $eavSetupFactory
     * @param Config $eavConfig
     * @param LoggerInterface $logger
     * @param Attribute $attributeResource
     * @param ModuleDataSetupInterface $moduleDataSetup
     */
    public function __construct(
        EavSetupFactory $eavSetupFactory,
        Config $eavConfig,
        LoggerInterface $logger,
        Attribute $attributeResource,
        ModuleDataSetupInterface $moduleDataSetup
    ) {
        $this->eavSetupFactory = $eavSetupFactory;
        $this->eavConfig = $eavConfig;
        $this->logger = $logger;
        $this->attributeResource = $attributeResource;
        $this->moduleDataSetup = $moduleDataSetup;
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function apply()
    {
        $this->moduleDataSetup->getConnection()->startSetup();
        $this->addDropdownAttribute();
        $this->moduleDataSetup->getConnection()->endSetup();
    }

    /**
     * @throws AlreadyExistsException
     * @throws LocalizedException
     * @throws \Zend_Validate_Exception
     */
    public function addDropdownAttribute()
    {
        $eavSetup = $this->eavSetupFactory->create();
        $eavSetup->addAttribute(
            Customer::ENTITY,
            'dropdown',
            [
                'type' => 'int',
                'input' => 'select',
                'label' => 'Dropdown Attribute',
                'required' => false,
                'visible' => false,
                'user_defined' => true,
                'system' => false,
                'is_visible_in_grid' => true,
                'is_used_in_grid' => true,
                'is_filterable_in_grid' => true,
                'is_searchable_in_grid' => true,
                'position' => 300,
                'nullable' => true,
                'source' => Options::class
            ]
        );

        $attributeSetId = $eavSetup->getDefaultAttributeSetId(Customer::ENTITY);
        $attributeGroupId = $eavSetup->getDefaultAttributeGroupId(Customer::ENTITY);
        $attribute = $this->eavConfig->getAttribute(Customer::ENTITY, 'dropdown');
        $attribute->setData('attribute_set_id', $attributeSetId);
        $attribute->setData('attribute_group_id', $attributeGroupId);
        $attribute->setData('used_in_forms', [
            'adminhtml_customer',
            'adminhtml_customer_address',
            'customer_account_edit',
            'customer_address_edit',
            'customer_register_address',
            'customer_account_create'
        ]);
        $this->attributeResource->save($attribute);
    }

    /**
     * @return array|string[]
     */
    public static function getDependencies()
    {
        return [];
    }

    /**
     * @return array|string[]
     */
    public function getAliases()
    {
        return [];
    }

    /**
     * @return void
     */
    public function revert()
    {
    }
}
```

1.1  create model file for option on below path
**app/code/Vendor/Extension/Model/Options.php**

```
<?php
namespace Vendor\Extension\Model;

use Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\Source\AbstractSource;

class Options extends AbstractSource
{
    public function getAllOptions()
    {
        $this->_options = [
            ['label' => 'Option1', 'value' => 1],
            ['label' => 'Option2', 'value' => 2],
            ['label' => 'Option3', 'value' => 3],
            ['label' => 'Other', 'value' => otherValue],
        ];
        return $this->_options;
    }
}
```

2.then create text filed customer attribute on path
**app/code/Vendor/Extension/Setup/Patch/Data/AddTextFieldAttribute.php**

```
<?php
namespace Vendor\Extension\Setup\Patch\Data;

use Magento\Customer\Model\Customer;
use Magento\Customer\Setup\CustomerSetup;
use Magento\Customer\Setup\CustomerSetupFactory;
use Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\Set;
use Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\SetFactory;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleDataSetupInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\Patch\DataPatchInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\Patch\PatchRevertableInterface;

class AddTextFieldAttribute implements DataPatchInterface, PatchRevertableInterface
{

    /**
     * @var ModuleDataSetupInterface
     */
    private $moduleDataSetup;
    /**
     * @var CustomerSetup
     */
    private $customerSetupFactory;
    /**
     * @var SetFactory
     */
    private $attributeSetFactory;

    /**
     * Constructor
     *
     * @param ModuleDataSetupInterface $moduleDataSetup
     * @param CustomerSetupFactory $customerSetupFactory
     * @param SetFactory $attributeSetFactory
     */
    public function __construct(
        ModuleDataSetupInterface $moduleDataSetup,
        CustomerSetupFactory     $customerSetupFactory,
        SetFactory               $attributeSetFactory
    )
    {
        $this->moduleDataSetup = $moduleDataSetup;
        $this->customerSetupFactory = $customerSetupFactory;
        $this->attributeSetFactory = $attributeSetFactory;
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function apply()
    {
        $this->moduleDataSetup->getConnection()->startSetup();
        /** @var CustomerSetup $customerSetup */
        $customerSetup = $this->customerSetupFactory->create(['setup' => $this->moduleDataSetup]);
        $customerEntity = $customerSetup->getEavConfig()->getEntityType(Customer::ENTITY);
        $attributeSetId = $customerEntity->getDefaultAttributeSetId();

        /** @var $attributeSet Set */
        $attributeSet = $this->attributeSetFactory->create();
        $attributeGroupId = $attributeSet->getDefaultGroupId($attributeSetId);

        $customerSetup->addAttribute(
            Customer::ENTITY,
            'new_attribute',
            [
                'label' => 'New Attribute',
                'input' => 'text',
                'type' => 'varchar',
                'source' => '',
                'required' => false,
                'position' => 40,
                'visible' => true,
                'system' => false,
                'is_used_in_grid' => true,
                'is_visible_in_grid' => true,
                'is_filterable_in_grid' => true,
                'is_searchable_in_grid' => false,
                'backend' => ''
            ]
        );

        $attribute = $customerSetup->getEavConfig()->getAttribute(Customer::ENTITY, 'new_attribute');
        $attribute->addData([
            'used_in_forms' => [
                'adminhtml_customer',
                'customer_account_create',
                'customer_account_edit'
            ]
        ]);
        $attribute->addData([
            'attribute_set_id' => $attributeSetId,
            'attribute_group_id' => $attributeGroupId

        ]);
        $attribute->save();

        $this->moduleDataSetup->getConnection()->endSetup();
    }

    public function revert()
    {
        $this->moduleDataSetup->getConnection()->startSetup();
        /** @var CustomerSetup $customerSetup */
        $customerSetup = $this->customerSetupFactory->create(['setup' => $this->moduleDataSetup]);
        $customerSetup->removeAttribute(\Magento\Customer\Model\Customer::ENTITY, 'new_attribute');

        $this->moduleDataSetup->getConnection()->endSetup();
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function getAliases()
    {
        return [];
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public static function getDependencies()
    {
        return [];
    }
}
```

3.add js for dependent attribute when only other option select then only show dropdown add js on your phtml file where frontend view structure for dropdown field and text field

```
 <script>
        require(["jquery"], function($){
            $(document).ready(function () {
                function toggleOther() {
                    const dropdownValue = $('#dropdownClassId').val();
                    const other = $('.field.otherFieldClass ');
                    if (dropdownValue.includes('otherValue')) {
                        other.show();
                    } else {
                        other.hide();
                    }
                }
                toggleOther();
                $('#dropdownClassId').on('change', function () {
                    toggleOther();
                });
        
            });
        })
 </script>
```

NOTE: change Dropdown field class and text field class id accodingly in above js and also change value of other option